# OpenCV fastNlMeansDenoisingMulti() should support 16-bit images but does it?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to denoise a 16-bit Picture of a sequence of pictures and using OpenCV's `fastNlMeansDenoisingMulti()` via Python. OpenCV documentation says this should work. but the compiler/interpreter says it can only handle several 8-bit formats. So is the documentation wrong or is the compiler wrong or did I miss something?

`fastNlMeansDenoisingColoredMulti()` with 8-bit Pictures works, `fastNlMeansDenoising()` with 16-bit works and `fastNlMeansDenoisingMulti()` works with 8-bit but not with 16-bit but it should.

```py
# imgs_r is an array of 16-bit images
dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingMulti(
    srcImgs = imgs_r,
    imgToDenoiseIndex = 3,
    temporalWindowSize = 7,
    h = [1.0],
    templateWindowSize = 7,
    searchWindowSize = 39,
    normType = 2)
```

`cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.0) /io/opencv/modules/photo/src/denoising.cpp:304: error: (-5:Bad argument) Unsupported image format! Only CV_8U, CV_8UC2, CV_8UC3 and CV_8UC4 are supported in function 'fastNlMeansDenoisingMulti_'`

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible that the Python binding generated by OpenCV has trouble deciding between the two signatures.

I managed to jump between lines 305 and 352 for the error, but opposite to what I passed for the arguments.

---

```
cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingMulti(imgs_r, 3, 7, [1.0], None, 7, 39)
```

`modules\photo\src\denoising.cpp:352: error: (-5:Bad argument) Unsupported depth! Only CV_8U is supported for NORM_L2 in function 'cv::fastNlMeansDenoisingMulti'`

---

```
cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingMulti(imgs_r, 3, 7, [1.0], None, 7, 39, cv.NORM_L1)
```

`modules\photo\src\denoising.cpp:305: error: (-5:Bad argument) Unsupported image format! Only CV_8U, CV_8UC2, CV_8UC3 and CV_8UC4 are supported in function 'fastNlMeansDenoisingMulti_'`

---

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I replaced the `2` with `cv2.NORM_L1`. the problem remains the same.

Comment: my answer is a work in progress. please be patient.

Comment: yeah I think this could be a bug in the opencv bindings. it's not picking the right signature for the given arguments